# 404 (Not Found) Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

No puedo acceder a mi formulario de edicion persiste el error

> jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:8000/admin/post/5/edit 404 (Not Found).

**Lo raro de esto es que si existe la ruta el metodo y el formulario(reutilizo formulario de creacion).**

**Estaba trabajando con una ruta para cada metodo, luego cambie por una ruta del tipo resource como asi tambien el controlador.**
Los metodo index,create,store funcionan, el problema esta al momento de editar mi formulario donde trato de reutilizar el mismo formulario de creacion.
Me podrian ayudar con este error?

Controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DataTables;
use App\Post;
use App\Category;
use App\Tag;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\SavePostsRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.posts.index');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $post = new Post();    
        $categories = Category::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();

        return view('admin.posts.partials.form', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(SavePostsRequest $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                // utiliza transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();

                $post = new Post;
                $post->title = $request->get('title');
                $post->url = str_slug($request->get('title'));
                $post->body = $request->get('body'); 
                $post->excerpt = $request->get('excerpt');
                $post->published_at = $request->has('published_at') ? Carbon::parse($request->get('published_at')) : null;
                $post->category_id = $request->get('category');
                $post->save();

                $post->tags()->attach($request->get('tags'));

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }        
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Post $post)
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();

        return view('admin.posts.partials.form', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));     
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(SavePostsRequest $request, Post $post)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()){
            try {
                // utiliza transacciones
                DB::beginTransaction();

                $post->title = $request->get('title');
                $post->url = str_slug($request->get('title'));
                $post->body = $request->get('body'); 
                $post->excerpt = $request->get('excerpt');
                $post->published_at = $request->has('published_at') ? Carbon::parse($request->get('published_at')) : null;
                $post->category_id = $request->get('category');
                $post->save();

                $post->tags()->attach($request->get('tags'));

                DB::commit();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                // anula la transacion
                DB::rollBack();
            }
        }  
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function dataTable()
    {
        $posts = Post::query()
        // $clientes = Client::with('company')
        // ->allowed()
        ->get();

        return dataTables::of($posts)
                ->addColumn('id', function ($posts){
                    return $posts->id;
                })  
                ->addColumn('titulo', function ($posts){
                    return $posts->title;
                })
                ->addColumn('extracto', function ($posts){
                    return $posts->excerpt;
                })                               
                ->addColumn('accion', function ($posts) {
                    return view('admin.posts.partials._action', [
                        'posts' => $posts,
                        'url_show' => route('admin.post.show', $posts->id),
                        'url_edit' => route('admin.post.edit', $posts->id),                       
                        'url_destroy' => route('admin.post.destroy', $posts->id)
                    ]);
                })

                ->addIndexColumn()   
                ->rawColumns(['titulo', 'extracto', 'accion'])                
                ->make(true);          
    }
}
```

Formulario

```
<div class="row">
    {!! Form::model($post, [
        'route' => $post->exists ? ['admin.post.update', $post->id] : 'admin.post.store',   
        'method' => $post->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
    ]) !!}    

    <div class="col-md-8">  
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Publicación</h3>
            </div>             
            <div class="box-body">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">                            
                    {!! Form::label('title', 'Titulo de la publicación') !!}                    
                    {!! Form::text('title', old('title', $post->title), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'title', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresa aqui el titulo de la publicación']) !!}
                </div>               

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Contenido de la publicación</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" rows="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa el contenido completo de la publicacion">{{ old('body', $post->body)}}</textarea>
                </div>                
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">        
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">Detalles de la publicacion</h3>                
            </div>            
            <div class="box-body">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Fecha de publicación:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                        </div>
                        <input name="published_at" 
                            class="form-control pull-right"

                            value="{{ old('published_at') }}"
                            type="text"
                            id="datepicker">
                    </div>                   
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">  
                    <label>Categorias</label>
                    <select name="category" id="category" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Selecciona una categoria</option>
                        @foreach ($categories as $category)
                            <option value="{{ $category->id }}"
                            {{ old('category', $post->category_id) == $category->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>                   
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Etiquetas</label>
                    <select name="tags[]" id="tags" class="form-control select2" 
                            multiple="multiple"
                            data-placeholder="Selecciona una o mas etiquetas" style="width: 100%;">
                        @foreach($tags as $tag)
                            <option {{ collect( old('tags', $post->tags->pluck('id')))->contains($tag->id) ? 'selected' : '' }} value="{{ $tag->id}}"> {{ $tag->name }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>              

                <div class="form-group">              
                    {!! Form::label('excerpt', 'Extracto de la publicación') !!}                    
                    {!! Form::textarea('excerpt', old('excerpt', $post->excerpt), ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'excerpt', 'placeholder' => 'Ingresa un exctracto de la publicación']) !!}
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Rutas

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'admin',
    'middleware' => 'auth'],   
function(){    
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');  
    Route::resource('post',        'PostsController', ['as' => 'admin']);    

});
Route::get('post/table',       'PostsController@dataTable')->name('post.table');
```

Script

```
$('#modal-btn-save').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $('#modal-body form'),
        url = form.attr('action'),
        method = $('input[name=_method]').val() == undefined ? 'POST' : 'PUT';

    form.find('.help-block').remove();
    form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

    for(instance in CKEDITOR.instances)
    {
        CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
    }

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        method: method,
        data : form.serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            form.trigger('reset');
            $('#modal').modal('hide');
            $('#datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();

            swal({
                type : 'success',
                title : '¡Éxito!',
                text : '¡Se han guardado los datos!'
            });
        },
        error : function (xhr) {
            var res = xhr.responseJSON;
            if ($.isEmptyObject(res) == false) {
                $.each(res.errors, function (key, value) {
                    $('#' + key)
                        .closest('.form-group')
                        .addClass('has-error')
                        .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>');
                });
            }
        }
    })
});
```

No estoy dando con la solución al problema!

ACTUALIZADO:

ejecutando php artisan route:list me muestra lo siguiente:

```
 GET|HEAD  | admin/post/create                   | admin.post.create        | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@create                            | web,auth     |  
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/post/{post}                   | admin.post.update        | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@update                            | web,auth     |  
|        | DELETE    | admin/post/{post}                   | admin.post.destroy       | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@destroy                           | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/post/{post}                   | admin.post.show          | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@show                              | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/post/{post}/edit              | admin.post.edit          | App\Http\Controllers\PostsController@edit                              | web,auth     |  
|        | POST      | admin/roles                         | admin.roles.store        | App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@store                             | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/roles                         | admin.roles.index        | App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@index                             | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/roles/create                  | admin.roles.create       | App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@create                            | web,auth     |  
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/roles/{role}                  | admin.roles.update       | App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@update                            | web,auth     |  
|        | DELETE    | admin/roles/{role}                  | admin.roles.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@destroy                           | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/roles/{role}/edit             | admin.roles.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\RolesController@edit                              | web,auth     |  
|        | POST      | admin/users                         | admin.users.store        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store                              | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users                         | admin.users.index        | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@index                              | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/create                  | admin.users.create       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@create                             | web,auth     |  
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/users/{user}                  | admin.users.update       | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@update                             | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}                  | admin.users.show         | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show                               | web,auth     |
|        | DELETE    | admin/users/{user}                  | admin.users.destroy      | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@destroy                            | web,auth     |  
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}/edit             | admin.users.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                               | web,auth     |
```

por ejemplo si voy al navegador y tipeo la ruta de edicion (
 `GET|HEAD  | admin/users/{user}/edit             | admin.users.edit         | App\Http\Controllers\UserController@edit                               | web,auth     |` )manualmente me muestra el formulario con los datos correspondientes,
cosa que no pasa si voy a admin/post/1/edit.

Para crear un nuevo post no hay problema, el problema esta en editar uno

adjunto imagen:
[image: Crear Post]

[image: Editar Post]

Como mencione anteriormente con este controlador venia trabajando rutas para cada metodo, luego pase a un controlador del tipo resource y rutas del tipo resource, todo lo demas lo venia reutilizando.

Comment: Podrías hacer un `php artisan route:list` y publicar el resultado? Cuándo realizás qué acción te aparece el error?

Comment: @azeós  realice un php artisan route:list, probe tambien php artisan route:clear,cache, config:cache, cache:clear. No se me ocurre otra cosa

Answer (score 1):

```
public function edit($id)
{
        $post = \App\Models\Post::find($id)
        $categories = Category::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();

        return view('admin.posts.partials.form', compact('post', 'categories', 'tags'));     
}
```

Hola Intenta de este modo y me comentas si funciono.

Comment: Genial funciona, no entiendo el porque funciona de esa manera si yo le estoy pasando como parametro (Post $post)? De todas formas gracias!!

Comment: Pasa que el parametro que estas casteando como un objeto **Post**  en realidad es un enterio no tiene una forma de auto buscar  por Id, he escuchado de eso pero no lo he visto funcionando, solo se que a mi no me funciona asi jejeje, por tal hago lo que te indique, en caso se que quieras mejorar cosas para una implementaciónd e API, remplaza el metodo FIND por FINDORFAIL con este ultimo en caso de no encontrar un objeto para el ID correspondiente, retorna un error 404.

Answer (score 0):

Modifica la propiedad route por action

```
{!! Form::model($post, [
        'action' => $post->exists ? ['admin.post.update', $post->id] : 'admin.post.store',   
        'method' => $post->exists ? 'PUT' : 'POST'
    ]) !!}
```

Comment: me sigue apareciendo el mismo error, usaba el mismo procedimiento antes.